# $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $c\in(x,x+\frac{1}{n})$, prove that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sup_{x \in[a,b]}|f'(x)-f'(c)|\longrightarrow0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

We have $f:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $c=c(x,n) \in (x,x+\frac{1}{n})$. Morover, we know that $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. I need to show that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f'(x)-f'(c)| \longrightarrow 0$.

I suppose it is obvious, but I have problem with putting it in words in some elegant way.

Comment: if $x=b$, what would be $f'(c)$ ?

Comment: You should probably write $c_x$ for $c$. Here's a hint: If $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Does $c\in (x,x+\frac1n)$ mean "for each $x\in[a,b]$ and each $n\in\Bbb N$ we pick $c=c(x,n)\in(x,x+\frac1n)$"? For as stated, you first fix$x$ and $n$ and hence cannot take supremum or limit by varying over them ...

Comment: You're right. I've changed it in message above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The function $f'$ is continuous on a compact interval, thus it is uniformly continuous. For every $c>0$, there exists $n$ such that $\mid x-y\mid <{1\over n}$ implies that $\mid f'(x)-f'(y)\mid <c$. This implies that for every $x\in [a,b], sup_{y\in [x, x+{1\over n}]}\mid f(x)-f(y)\mid <c$.